# Debug Java application from Eclipse which has not been started by a Run Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have an Eclipse Java project which I run via a Debug configuration. The application starts a bunch of other external Java applications. Is it possible to debug those applications from within Eclipse?

The only way I can think of is somehow using remote debugging, but as the applications run locally there has to be an easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an **eclipse remote debugging**.

look at the this tutorial to make your set up

http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

make sure you also set a debug port in your remote application launcher

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I already know how to remotely debug and I'm pretty sure it works well in my situation (see question) - I just wanted to know, if there is any alternative for locally executed applications.

Comment: There seems to be no alternative to remote debugging. Your answer is from all others (which are btw atm all correct) most to the point, therfore I'll accept it as correct answer and upvote all others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

I think this will help...
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: There is nothing about debugging application started without Debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start those applications with debug mode. Take a look at this http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2011/07/java-debugging-tutorial-example-tips.html

Comment: Hm, seems that I indeed have to do remote debugging on localhost. Thanks for the interesting link!

Comment: Well I think debugging a java application is always done in terms of client/server.

Comment: If you mean application == server and jdb == client you're right.